# How to measure the current drawn by RaspberryPi at a partcular time?

Tags: raspbian

On Raspberrypi, the command vcgencmd measure_volts gives the voltage.
Is there a way to measure the current being drawn by the Raspberry Pi at a particular time?
I have a requirement of measuring energy consumption of RaspberryPi, but do not find any software tool to do so.

Comment: You can't measure it without including external test equipment between your power supply and your RPi.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no RPi equipped with any facility to measure its own current. I bought [this device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07X3HST7V) recently which meets most of my needs. There are many similar products, so review the specs to learn which one works best for you.

[image]

Comment: Will we be able to read the USB C Power Meter Tester energy consumption readings through programs, say python program at run time?

Comment: @SAROJPANDA: I don't know the answer to that question. I suspect that's not supported, but I do not know that for a fact. Check with the manufacturer - or ask a question of the seller on Amazon's product page (referenced in my answer).